# Best way to keep/cach Dataset for reuse on a desktop application

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, caching, dataset

I have a webservice which returns a dataset to client desktop application when ever they open the application , nothing is sent back to Database.
The desktop application requires this dataset for its entire life time

What is the best way to keep this dataset out of memory something like caching in ASP.net ?

Is there any possibility to keep it as XML and take it back when application looks for data ?

This is a product list feeding to the client application , the product list is updated from a web application globally , so if client needs latest data then there are ways to retrieve from web but basically only one time loading during the startup of the application and keep using it but having 9,000 rows i am concerned about application performance and memory, not sure how much memory will be consumed for a 9,000 rows dataset

Sample code will be much appreciated

Comment: If it is sent every time the app starts why does it need to be saved?

Comment: Questions about `Best ways` are really hard to answer. Especially if so little context is given.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the Cache Aside Pattern.

Basically, it provides a well-known way to put a concrete object in the cache.....with an expiration policy (don't re-invent the wheel, use what is available).

The pattern says "give me what's in the cache....and if its not there, here is the real method to go and populate the object".

You would run the below code on the thin client, and where I have "new ClaimsPrincipal", you would make a call to your web service and get the data you need.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589799.aspx

https://blog.cdemi.io/design-patterns-cache-aside-pattern/

Here is an example:

```
   public class PrincipalMemoryCacheAside // : IPrincipalCacheAside
    {
        public const string CacheKeyPrefix = "PrincipalMemoryCacheAsideKey";

        public ClaimsPrincipal GetTheClaimsPrincipal(string uniqueIdentifier)
        {
            string cacheKey = this.GetFullCacheKey(uniqueIdentifier);
            ClaimsPrincipal cachedOrFreshPrincipal = GetFromCache<ClaimsPrincipal>(
                cacheKey, 
                () =>
                {
                    ClaimsPrincipal returnPrinc = null;

                    /* You would go hit your web service here to populate your object */
                    ClaimsIdentity ci = new GenericIdentity(this.GetType().ToString());
                    ci.AddClaim(new Claim("MyType", "MyValue"));
                    returnPrinc  = new ClaimsPrincipal(ci);


                    return returnPrinc;
                });

            return cachedOrFreshPrincipal;
        }

        private TEntity GetFromCache<TEntity>(string key, Func<TEntity> valueFactory) where TEntity : class
        {

            ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
            //// the lazy class provides lazy initializtion which will evaluate the valueFactory expression only if the item does not exist in cache
            var newValue = new Lazy<TEntity>(valueFactory);
            CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy { SlidingExpiration = new TimeSpan(0, 60, 0), Priority = CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable };
            ////The line below returns existing item or adds the new value if it doesn't exist
            var value = cache.AddOrGetExisting(key, newValue, policy) as Lazy<TEntity>;
            return (value ?? newValue).Value; // Lazy<T> handles the locking itself
        }

        private string GetFullCacheKey(string uniqueIdentifier)
        {
            string returnValue = CacheKeyPrefix + uniqueIdentifier;
            return returnValue;
        }
    }
```